# Passing Comparator to super constructor

Tags: java, comparator

I need to implement my own generic binary heap in java using an arraylist. It needs to support max heaps and min heaps. This should be implemented by passing a Comparator to the BinaryHeap constructor.

So I guess depending on what the compare-method in the passed Comparator does, it's either a min or a max heap. I thought I'd make a regular PQ (which is default min) and then write a MaxPQ class that extends PQ and pass a Comparator to the super constructor. But I need to call the super in the first line, so I don't know where to initialize the Comparator. Any ideas?

Here's the code for the MaxHeap:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class MaxHeap<Bid> extends BinaryHeap<Bid> {

    public MaxHeap(){

        MaxComp maxComp = new MaxComp();
        super(maxComp);

    }

}

class MaxComp implements Comparator<Bid>{
    public int compare(Bid a, Bid b){
        return (a.val - b.val);
    }

}
```

Tried Dmitrys advice `super(new MaxComp());`, which produced `"BinaryHeap<Bid>(MaxComp) is undefined"`. This is the super constructor which takes a Comparator:

```
public class BinaryHeap<E>{

    private Comparator<? super E> comp;
    private ArrayList<E> array;

    private int last;   // index of last element

    public BinaryHeap(Comparator<? super E> comp){
        this.comp = comp;
        array = new ArrayList<E>();
    }
```

Comment: Please show some code, so it's clearer what you want to do, and how you want to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by PQ?

Comment: PriorityQueue, thought they were basically synonoyms

Comment: Heaps by definition are tree structures, where a parent node is by comparison smaller/greater then its child nodes. A queue is a list structure. However, you can transform a tree into a list and vice versa.

Comment: @SME_Dev there is nothing in CS which says that queue has to be list structured. PQ are usually trees.

Comment: btw, instead of `MaxHeap<Bid> extends ...` use `MaxHeap extends ...`, because you already specified with which type you're working with `extends BinaryHeap<Bid>`. That is your problem, I believe.

Comment: That removed the error. But I don't understasnd why that would matter :)

Comment: @Dmitry i know Wikipedia isn't usually an academic source, but it offently contains common opinions. It [states for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28abstract_data_type%29): _A queue is an example of a linear data structure, or more abstractly a sequential collection_ . When using a term like 'Queue', you shouldn't mix it with implementation details to redefine it in accordingly.

Comment: @SME_Dev hm, you kind of right here. But PQ then should be treated differently from normal queue (also - Wikipedia): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue

Comment: @Dmitry :D your link even states _priority queues [...] are conceptually distinct from heaps_

Comment: It's called a priority queue because it has a naturally defined default dequeue operation, so it's conceptually similar to a queue even if it's not implementationally similar. It's not a queue, it's a priority queue.

Comment: @SME_Dev conceptually does not mean internally :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just initialize it like follows:

```
super(new MaxComp());
```

Also, instead of `MaxHeap<Bid> extends ...` use `MaxHeap extends ...`, because you already specified with which type you're working with `extends BinaryHeap<Bid>`. That's why you can't call `super` constructor with your `Comparator`. Reason is that generic type `Bid` in `class MaxHeap<Bid>` is used instead of actual class `Bid`.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, I'll edit the post again

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist "doesn't work" is too broad reason. What exactly it complains about?

Comment: Edited the original post now